# Calling C++ functions from Java

Tags: java, c++, google-app-engine, java-native-interface

I am developing a Java application in which I need to call some C++ functions (from Google Talk library libjingle) . The objective is to run it all on Google App Engine (which only supports Python or Java).

How can I do this?

Comment: With JNI, Why dou you already have that in your tags ?!

Comment: do you specifically require libjingle or will any XMPP library do? you can see a list of available libraries [here](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to define `native` methods in your java code for whatever you want to be implemented in C++ and directly access your native code. Then you run `javah` on your code and it will generate the C header files for you and you'll need to provide C++ implementations.

The native methods you can call from your Java code like any other methods and still they'll have their implementation written in C++ and talking to whatever other native library directly.

You then need to set the java.library.path system property to include the shared C/C++ libraries that you require: the google library and your own JNI implementation library would be required in this case.

Comment: Thank you all. Do you know if JNI and native code in C++ work fine with Google App Engine?

Comment: no, they don't. app engine [doesn't support native code or compiled binaries](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html#The_Sandbox), via JNI or anything else. From that link: "An app cannot provide or directly invoke any native JNI code."

asaf's comment above is on the right track. you probably want to use app engine's [built in xmpp api](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/xmpp/) instead.

Answer (score 5):

If the library has C bindings through a DLL/SO, I usually prefer writing wrappers in Java using [Java Native Access (JNA)](http://jna.java.net/) rather than writing the bindings in C/C++ using the [Java Native Interface (JNI)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/).  The former is easier to manipulate as the JNI access to  Java objects is a real pain in the neck.  However, it's not as obvious to wrap C++ classes using that API.

You might also want to look into the [Simplified Wrapper and Interface Generator (SWIG)](http://www.swig.org/) for automating part of this process!

Answer (score 2):

You can't run native code on App Engine - only JRE code. If there's no avoiding the native code, you'll need to run this part of your app on another system, and call it from your App Engine app - or use the built-in [XMPP API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/xmpp/), in this case.