# call c++ library from java application

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling C++ functions from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626787/calling-c-functions-from-java)

Hi

how to call c++ library from java and use it

any suggestion example, will be highly appretiated

Best regards

Comment: What kind of libraries? Be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

Try [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/), it is more friendly than JNI.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, you need to use [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface).