# How to get in a Java program, CPU performance stats on Intel CPU?

Tags: java, c++, cpu, intel, performancecounter

There is something called, [Intel Performance Counter Monitor](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-performance-counter-monitor), which gives you the stats of the event, e.g.;

```
 EXEC  : instructions per nominal CPU cycle
 IPC   : instructions per CPU cycle
 FREQ  : relation to nominal CPU frequency='unhalted clock ticks'/'invariant timer ticks' (includes Intel Turbo Boost)
 AFREQ : relation to nominal CPU frequency while in active state (not in power-saving C state)='unhalted clock ticks'/'invariant timer ticks while in C0-state'  (includes Intel Turbo Boost)
 L3MISS: L3 cache misses 
 L2MISS: L2 cache misses (including other core's L2 cache *hits*) 
 L3HIT : L3 cache hit ratio (0.00-1.00)
 L2HIT : L2 cache hit ratio (0.00-1.00)
 L3MPI : number of L3 cache misses per instruction
 L2MPI : number of L2 cache misses per instruction
 READ  : bytes read from memory controller (in GBytes)
 WRITE : bytes written to memory controller (in GBytes)
 IO    : bytes read/written due to IO requests to memory controller (in GBytes); this may be an over estimate due to same-cache-line partial requests
 TEMP  : Temperature reading in 1 degree Celsius relative to the TjMax temperature (thermal headroom): 0 corresponds to the max temperature
 energy: Energy in Joules


 Core (SKT) | EXEC | IPC  | FREQ  | AFREQ | L3MISS | L2MISS | L3HIT | L2HIT | L3MPI | L2MPI | TEMP

   0    0     0.10   0.52   0.19    0.74    1502 K   3612 K    0.58    0.53    0.00    0.01     43
   1    0     0.19   0.67   0.28    0.80    1548 K   3090 K    0.50    0.69    0.00    0.00     46
   2    0     0.06   0.48   0.13    0.73    1060 K   1768 K    0.40    0.57    0.01    0.01     46
   3    0     0.07   0.55   0.12    0.72    1142 K   1489 K    0.23    0.47    0.01    0.01     42
   4    0     0.06   0.54   0.10    0.75     894 K   2102 K    0.57    0.50    0.00    0.01     43
   5    0     0.04   0.49   0.09    0.73     669 K   1377 K    0.51    0.57    0.00    0.01     46
   6    0     0.03   0.43   0.08    0.73     888 K   1543 K    0.42    0.30    0.01    0.01     46
   7    0     0.24   0.80   0.29    0.90    1285 K   2132 K    0.40    0.78    0.00    0.00     42
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 SKT    0     0.10   0.61   0.16    0.78    8992 K     17 M    0.47    0.61    0.00    0.01     42
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 TOTAL  *     0.10   0.61   0.16    0.78    8992 K     17 M    0.47    0.61    0.00    0.01     N/A

 Instructions retired: 2702 M ; Active cycles: 4420 M ; Time (TSC): 3411 Mticks ; C0 (active,non-halted) core residency: 20.75 %

 C1 core residency: 21.34 %; C3 core residency: 11.65 %; C6 core residency: 46.26 %; C7 core residency: 0.00 %;
 C2 package residency: 0.00 %; C3 package residency: 0.00 %; C6 package residency: 0.00 %; C7 package residency: 0.00 %;

 PHYSICAL CORE IPC                 : 1.22 => corresponds to 30.57 % utilization for cores in active state
 Instructions per nominal CPU cycle: 0.20 => corresponds to 4.95 % core utilization over time interval
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

          |  READ |  WRITE |    IO  | CPU energy |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 SKT   0     2.03     0.94     1.31      18.18     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now, this software also has option to call from inside of program. If you call some functions inside of that program, it gives you the stats of those function like in the example. My problem is all the software, the libraries and that code parts are written in and for C++. As I searched in the internet a few people got together and opened an open source project as Java Performance Counter Monitor. However, that project last updated at 2011-2012, even the website was built under Sun and not sure it will work under Java 8.

So my question is there any performance analysis program or any suggestion on how can I use IPCM for my Java program?

Comment: You can use c++ libraries using JNI. You can read more on how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626787/calling-c-functions-from-java) on StackOverflow. GL.

Comment: @TT. would that create an overhead for the stats? I mean I want to see as purely as possible the stats of my program, is this method would change the stats so much? If it does any suggestion to how to refract then as much as possible.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, **tool**, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Try [software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) @ Stack Exchange.

Comment: It looks like the Intel Performance Monitor writes to the OS; then the user-space, Intel-provided libraries read from there.  In other words, it looks like the Linux libraries read from [/proc` filesystem](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html), the Windows libraries from [Performance Counters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371643%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), etc.  One possibility for you is JNI, perhaps a better possibility is a Java library for the OS-specific performance counters.

Comment: Q: What OS(s) are you targeting?

Comment: Personally I think the overhead is minimal. I also think since JAVA is intended to run on multiple platforms, that there is no platform independent way to measure the CPU performance. So I think there probably is no other way than to use a native library using JNI/JNA (I could be wrong though). If you still want to pursue a JAVA library I suggest you follow the advice given by Captain Obvlious. GL!

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I wasn't sure that Software Recommendations has users interested in this low level tools, that was the reason I posted at here.

Comment: @paulsm4 Linux at the moment.

Comment: BTW The details of which measures are available and how many you can enable at once is specific to the model of CPU you have.  This makes it a maintenance nightmare unless you know exactly which model of CPU you want to support.